# Why doesn't this query work with date specified?

Tags: php, mysql

I have connected my database using php. When I press the delete button , a php file connects to another php file which has the following code:

```
<?php include("dbconfig.php");
 $memberID = $_GET['memberID'];
 $ISBN = $_GET['ISBN'];
 $copyNr = $_GET['copyNr'];
 $date_of_borrowing = $_GET['date_of_borrowing'];

//getting id of the data from url
$sql="DELETE FROM borrows WHERE ISBN=$ISBN AND memberID=$memberID AND copyNr=$copyNr AND date_of_borrowing=$date_of_borrowing";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


//redirecting to the display page (borrows_table.php in our case)
//header("Location:borrows_table.php");

?>
```

When I run this code without the "AND date_of_borrowing=$date_of_borrowing";"
it deletes the tuple correctly, but when it is as shown , nothing happens. I have checked that the variables memberID,ISBN,copyNr and date_of_borrowing are in fact correct when given in this file. So what could be the problem?

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). The solution to that is also likely to solve the problem about the date.

Comment: dates need to be quoted.

Comment: @tim best answer! thank you!

Comment: Look out if someone dose this (SQL Injection) `$_GET['memberID'] = '"" OR 1 --'` because your Query will become this: `DELETE FROM borrows WHERE ISBN="" OR 1` which will delete  everything in that table.

Comment: `date_of_borrowing=$date_of_borrowing` - is also prolly going to explode as there is no quotes around the date string ( `date_of_borrowing='$date_of_borrowing'`).  But there is no point putting them in as it wont matter if you prepare your query to prevent the SQL injection.

Comment: 2019-05-19 = 1995 . That's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an echo $sql before querying. Mysql only accepts following format
YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS
For Ex: 2019-05-20 12:39:30 
And also
put your date in quotes

```
$sql="DELETE FROM borrows WHERE ISBN=$ISBN AND memberID=$memberID AND copyNr=$copyNr AND date_of_borrowing='$date_of_borrowing'";

echo $sql;

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: ...and most importantly, see about sqlinjection, and the importance of prepared and bound queries.

Answer (score -1):

The thing you are getting wrong is date field is parsing wrong value mysql read date as `yyyy-mm-dd` format so you have to format your `$date_of_borrowing` to `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format, then it will work fine.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_of_borrowing)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Works fine in my case, and make sure put the date inside `''`

PS - Please do some filtering and mysql injection checking before process the data.

Comment: How do I do the first thing?

Comment: how do you know what format the date is? it's not show in the code.

Comment: sometimes user do not format dates they just put it that way and it does not work.. @thriteenchess

Comment: It doesn't matter if the date is wrong as it's a MySQL syntax error without quotes around it.

Comment: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_of_borrowing)->format('Y-m-d'); should work fine in my case

Comment: @thriteenchess did not mentioned that he is getting any syntax error. user is saying "nothing happens"

Comment: @BrainDeveloper - your right, I haven't used an Un-prepared query in like 7 years ... lol.  I was thinking this was a syntax error `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_col = 2019-01-01`  (Without the quotes).  I think the last time I did that (unprepared) I was still using `mysql_*` functions...

Comment: @BrainDeveloper - not sure who down voted your answer (I never or very rarely downvote), but I would offer a suggestion.  Add the code to convert the date format, that you used in the above comment to the question.  And I would turn the formats into code, as it's a bit messy.  You can do inline code with the backtic `, and a code block with ctrl+k,

Comment: For example `'yyyy-mm-dd'` looks better then just  'yyyy-mm-dd'. Cheers!

Comment: Sure, good luck!   SO can be very judgemental.  I say that because I feel that way when someone downvotes without any constructive criticism.  I cleaned it up a bit more for you too, hope you don't mind!.

Comment: You can also shorten it to this `$date = (new DateTime($date_of_borrowing))->format('Y-m-d');`  After PHP 5.4 at least, If i remember when the `(new foo)->` chaining was added.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Some People Doesn't Get The Meaning Of Help.. Your Help Is Very Much Appreciated.. I Owe You One.. Cheers :)

Comment: my vote, your answer is that something you can't possibly know is the problem. Guessing is not helpful. I could answer with `$conn` is not a valid MySQL connection - I have as much information on that variable, as you have on `$date_of_borrowing`